# Core Data Relationship Saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am trying to figure out how to use Core Data with relationships. I have used Core Data before, but only the very basics sans relationships (which worked for my needs at the time).

[image: Relationship]

I have a `Trip` entity that can have many `Node`s. When the user presses a "Start" button, I want to initialize the `Trip` entity and start storing all of the `Node`s inside of that `Trip`, and then when the user presses a "Stop" button, I want it to calculate all of the `Trip` attributes and store it all together. How do I save with respect to these entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the MO subclasses using the IDE, it will create methods for setting the nodesInTrip and tripsInNode relationships.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't created the MO subclasses yet. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops! It was under the time limit and I forgot to come back. Sorry about that!